# Concatenate string & list

Tags: python

I have a list and a string below:

```
fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'plum']
mystr = 'i like the following fruits: '
```

How can I concatenate them so I get (keeping in mind that the enum may change size) :

```
i like the following fruits: 

banana
apple
plum
```

I need the `mystr` in the starting and fruit names one by one as shown

Comment: Tru `mystr+' '.join(fruits)`

Comment: To achieve the exact desired result as in your question, you can do this: `print("\n\n".join([mystr, ",".join(fruits)]))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.format`, and `str.join` to get your required output.

**Ex:**

```
fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'plum']
mystr = 'i like the following fruits: \n\n{}'.format("\n".join(fruits))
print(mystr)
```

**Output:**

```
i like the following fruits: banana, apple, plum
```

Comment: can i get the output as i mentioned in my question. (edited)

Comment: Sure. Updated solution.

Comment: Can i have the code ?